# disable all incoming links with JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Without using jquery, how to I turn off any future links? as my ajax result returned html which contain `<a href=""></a>` tags.

Comment: Cant you just remove the `href` in the code you returned?

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX callback function, you can run this code which will remove the href attribute from the links:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].removeAttribute("href");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzjkf2uv/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use providing ID for ajax loaded content

> getElementsByTagName

**WORKING CODE :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function(){/*

//removes attribute 
suggested by : Duncan Cowan

var anchors = document.getElementById("myAjaxResult");
anchors = anchors.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].removeAttribute("href");
}*/

//NOTE: Prevents default actions (has default anchor's css)
var anchors = document.getElementById("myAjaxResult").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
    function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  );
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myAjaxResult">
 <a href="www.google.com">Test 2</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Test 2</a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:**

call the anchor remove function on ajax SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering using CSS for that?

If yes, here it is:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```